# Need to fasten my Java code

Tags: java, performance, palindrome

I'm trying to solve a problem from SPOJ. But the problem for me is not the actual difficulty of the algorithm; it is the performance of my Java code as it usually results in time limit exceeded error.

I heard that Java is notorious for its slow performance on contest problems compared to C/C++; however, the only language in which I can code for now is Java. Thus, I am asking for suggestions to make my code neater and faster. Below is my solution and the source problem.

```
public class NextPalindrome {

 public static BigInteger secondHalf(BigInteger b) {
    String s = b.toString();
    int n = s.length();
    if(n==1){
        return b;
    }
    String end = s.substring((n + 1) / 2, n);
    BigInteger End = new BigInteger(end);
    return End;
 }

 public static BigInteger reverse(BigInteger b) {
    String s = b.toString();
    int n = s.length();
    String beg = b.toString();
    String reversebeg = "";
    while (true) {
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversebeg = reversebeg + beg.charAt(i);
        }
        break;
    }
    BigInteger reverse = new BigInteger(reversebeg);

    return reverse;
 }

 public static BigInteger firstHalf(BigInteger b) {
    String s = b.toString();
    int n = s.length();
    if(n==1){
        return b;
    }
    String beg = s.substring(0, n / 2);
    BigInteger Beg = new BigInteger(beg);
    return Beg;
 }

 public static BigInteger nextPalindrom(BigInteger b) {

    String s = b.toString();

    int n = s.length();
    if(n==1){
        if(b.equals(9)){
            return BigInteger.valueOf(11);
        } else {
            return b.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        }
    }
    if (n % 2 == 1&&n>1) {
        Character c = s.charAt(n / 2);
        String C = c.toString();
        BigInteger med = new BigInteger(C);
        BigInteger beg = firstHalf(b);

        BigInteger end = secondHalf(b);

        if (reverse(beg).compareTo(end) <= 0) {
            beg.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
            if (med.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(9)) == 0) {
                c = '0';
            } else {
                med = med.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
            }
        }
        String temp = beg.toString();
        String temp1 = reverse(beg).toString();
        C = med.toString();
        String result = temp + C;
        result = result.concat(temp1);
        BigInteger B = new BigInteger(result);

        return B;
    }
    BigInteger beg = firstHalf(b);

    BigInteger end = secondHalf(b);

    if (reverse(beg).compareTo(end) <= 0) {
        beg = beg.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

    }
    String temp = beg.toString();
    String temp1 = reverse(beg).toString();

    String result = temp.concat(temp1);
    BigInteger B = new BigInteger(result);
    return B;

 }

 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = in.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        BigInteger big = new BigInteger(in.readLine());
        BigInteger palindrom = nextPalindrom(big);
        System.out.println(palindrom);
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Your question better fits this site concept: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would start by not turning the number into a string.

Comment: @Blender I did it by not turning the string into a number.

Comment: I'm not sure what complexity the conversion from `String` to `BigInteger` has, but `BigInteger.toString()` is `O(digits²)`. With up to `1000000` digits, that's prohibitive. What you need is an array of digits. These can conveniently be `char`s. Then work with the `char[]`. Being a palindrome is not an arithmetic property, but a property of the digit sequence aka string representation. Being larger is easily translated to a condition on the digit sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had to use BigInteger because some numbers can be of 1000000 digits long. Now I see how I can do it with char[] array.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger is used for precise calculations, but it is SLOW. int or long would be better here.

And then there are many conversions to and from String, which are slow, too.

And some slow String operations...

So I would recommend to use int or long
and the static helper methods of Integer or Long
to manipulate the raw bits of the numbers.

That should lead to the best performance of your program.

Comment: The numbers can have up to `1000000` digits, no good for `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Without commenting on your code, which others addressed, you shouldn't believe everything you hear about Java's slow performance. You would have to try very hard to think of an algorithm for a competition problem that would run under the time limit in C++ but not in Java. It was your choice of *algorithm*, not Java, that was causing the slowness.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. I apologize if I was ignorant about the issue that I was only vaguely aware of.